# Удаление записей из бд MYSQL

Tags: php

Ребят, подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка в коде, не могу понять, нужно удалить запись по id, получаю глобальный массив GET по id, в запросе указываю что в id будет подставляться значение из моего глобального массива. Удаление нужно совершить по ссылке.
Весь код:

```
$host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'user';
    $password = '';
    $db_name = 'workers';
    $link=mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db_name) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    mysqli_query($link, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");

    $id =$_GET['id'];
    $delete = "DELETE FROM workers WHERE id='$id'";
    $query_del[]= mysqli_query($link,$delete)or die(mysqli_error($link));
<a href="Project.php?id=<?php

                echo $query_del['id']?>"
                >Удалить</a>`введите сюда код`
```

Comment: Никогда не подставляйте значения непосредственно в текст запроса, используйте подготавливаемые выражения и привязку переменных. http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: И для отладки кода уберите из него все лишнее. Например чтение других таблиц, оно к вопросу явно отношение не имеет. И так читать нельзя. Читайте все поля одновременно. СУБД не гарантирует, что отдаст результаты запросов `SELECT id FROM workers WHERE id>0` и `SELECT name FROM workers WHERE id>0` в одном и том же порядке... (не говоря уже о том, что ваш подход очень сильно грузит БД, потому что ей приходится одну и ту же работу выполнять много раз)

Comment: И для отладки распечатайте значение `$id`, может оно пустое, СУБД в этом случае никаких ошибок не вернет, потому что запрос корректен, но и ничего не сделает, потому что условие `id=NULL` всегда ложно

Comment: Я вас немного понял, только меня волнует один вопрос, откуда у меня в параметр id в GET попадает значение

Comment: Вы оказались правы, моя $id пустая

Comment: Значения в $_GET попадают из URL который открывают `.../file.plp?id=XXX`

Comment: Это получается, когда я выбираю ссылку рядом со значением?

Comment: Что значит "ссылку рядом со значением". Вы сами формируете текст ссылок и если вы в текст ссылки вписали правильные параметры, то они конечно там будут. А если не вписывали, то браузер или сервер их сами не придумают

Comment: Понял, спасибо вам большое за помощь, буду исправлять указанные ошибки

Comment: не используйте `get`- запросы для удаления

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое за совет

Comment: Буду использовать POST